# Find all links *without* a class

Tags: .net, watin

I have a page which could have up to 20-30 links. Some of these links could have a class depending on other factors.

I would like to randomly choose a link out of the ones that don't have the class.

Is there any way of doing this with watin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `.Filter()` it doesn't seem to like trying to filter to items without a particular value..... so.... I came up with the below monstrosity; it is not exactly elegant but it works on my test page, and should work almost all of the time given a small-ish number of links and a decent percentage of these links not having a class.

As it is possible that it will not find a link without a class / blank class, if so it will explicitly throw an exception.  Implementing a store of which links have been tried wouldn't be too difficult, and would only throw an exception if there were not any links without class defined.  The below was quicker to implement and could be "good enough".

```
var browser = ie.Page<MyPageClass>();  //obviously anonymized here.
int numberOfLinks = browser.Document.Links.Count;
Random random = new Random();
int randomNum = random.Next(0, numberOfLinks);
int counter = 0;
int maxTimesToTry = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < maxTimesToTry; i++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(browser.Document.Links[randomNum].ClassName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("url: " + browser.Document.Links[randomNum].Url);
        break;                    
    }
    else
    {
        randomNum = random.Next(0, numberOfLinks);
    }
    counter++;
}

if (counter == maxTimesToTry)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to find a link without a class in {0} tries", maxTimesToTry));
}
```

Tested on WatiN 2.1, IE9, Win7, NUnit 2.5